# Ruby, print all the hashes "subfield" in one row

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have a JSON array structured like this:

```
{"elements":[{"ECL001":{"description":"First Element", "max_level":3, "size":10}},{"ECL002":{"description":"Second Element", "max_level":4, "size":1}}]}
```

I'm parsing my structure and then I print data if condition are satisfied.

```
require 'json'

x = JSON.parse(File.open('data_elements.dat').read)

elements = x["elements"]

elements.each do |elem_specific|
  elem_specific.each do |id, data|
    if data['max_level'] > 3
       puts "#{data['description']}, #{data['max_level']}, #{data[size]}"
    end
  end
end
```

It's work correctly, but is there a faster solution to prints data?

I mean ... Is possible replace this

```
puts "#{data['description']}, #{data['max_level']}, #{data[size]}"
```

with something like

```
puts "#{data[*ALL]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I found this:

```
puts "#{data.values}" # Print all Values

puts "#{data.keys}" # Print all Keys
```